# ASP.NET - FormView - Datasource update only some of the fields

Tags: asp.net, objectdatasource, formview

I have a ASP.NET page that contains a formview and ObjectDataSource.  On the page I only have 4 fields that are bound to fields in my datasource.  My datasource contains 10 fields.  When I call an update it is setting the 6 fields I am not binding to to null.  The only way I can find it get around this is to add hidden fields for the 6 unbound fields and bind them to the datasource.

Is there anyway around this without using hidden fields?  I would think that it should only update the fields you are binding to and ignore the others.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to just change by hand the Update Code on the datasource of your formview.

Just remove the fields that you do not won to update. Its a simple SQL command.

Comment: That won't work for me.  The reason is I am doing about a 10 step process on 10 different pages with only one object and storing the object in the session when i move between pages.  So when I set the object in the session it is reseting all the values that are not on the current page.  I don't want to run the sql until they have finished the last page so I need to store the state of the object in between pages somehow without losing values.

Comment: @Dan I have lost you, if you can place some code here then maybe I can help you more.